# Computer randomly loggin-out on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

This happens really randomly, usually while I am typing something. Any idea what it could be?

In case that can help, here's my logs from `pastebinit ~/.xsession-errors`  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6144800/

**EDIT** happened again. Logs from System Logs/Xorg.0.log just after relogging :
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6155272/

Comment: I might be mistaken, but to me it seems the .xsession-errors does not show anything unusual. It might be of help if you also uploaded /var/log/Xorg.0.log, best in a state right after you are being logged out unintentionally. Some of the possible reasons that come to my mind right now: a) too little free RAM and no swap space, b) a bug in the graphics driver, c) faulty hardware, d) a memory leak in a running program. But let's see if your Xorg.0.log has more information before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Ok ... as soon as this happens again, I'll post this. This is a brand new laptop, so I guess there's enough free ram. I do hope it's not the "faulty hardware" one!!!

Comment: There you go! Logs from Xorg.0.log just after it happened again :(

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I made a mistake. Xorg.0.log was obviously overwritten when X.org restarted after whatever error occured. In this case the relevant information had at the point you posted Xorg.0.log already been moved to Xorg.1.log... I'm sorry I didn't think about this before... If you still remember how often you restarted X.org since the crash, could you check the Xorg.*.log file corresponding to the session before the logout? If not, if it happens again, please post Xorg.1.log as well.

Comment: In fact, I found some people having the exact same problem (this was mostly happening while using Pure Data), and apparently installing intel's graphic chip's drivers did the trick. I installed them and since that haven't had any crash! Let's see ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out installing the drivers from my builtin Intel graphic chip solved the problem. Instructions for installation can be found here : https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2